# Is it possible to relinquish the inheritance rights in India before death of the parents?

Tags: india, inheritance

In the case when a parent dies(P1), usually the property is bequeathed to their close family (wife(W) and children(C1, C2, C3)). Is it possible to relinquish the right to the property that should be bequeathed in future to a child(C3), by himself?
If so, could someone please explain the procedure?

Comment: What religion is the parent and child C3? And has P1 made a will?

Comment: Religion is Hindu, the parent hasn't made a will yet